# Remove places bar in OpenFileDialog C#

Tags: c#, openfiledialog

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Difficult to imagine why would you like to do it!

Comment: I would say you could do this by getting the window handle of the places bar and hiding it using a p/invoked `ShowWindow` win32 api call.

Answer (score 2):

Check this out : [Customize Your Open File Dialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300434.aspx)

EDIT:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300434.aspx
>
> When coding against the Open File
>   common dialog in the **Win32 API, you
>   can set a style to hide the places
>   bar**. But like other features of the
>   Win32 common dialogs, **this setting
>   seems to have gotten lost in the
>   migration to the .NET Framework**.
>   Creating a common dialog has never
>   been easier than it is in the
>   Framework, but this simplicity comes
>   at the cost of some flexibility. **In
>   addition, in managed code there is no
>   way to extend the layout of the dialog
>   with additional controls.**

Comment: I've read that article before, it shows only how to define custom places bar. There's no mentioning of removing it.

Comment: What or who is being quoted in the quote in the answer?

Answer (score 0):

There is no support in the .net framework for substantial changes to the existing dialogs.
However solutions like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/CustomizeFileDialog.aspx) can help you.